# Windows phone app in windows 7 PC

Tags: windows-phone-7

I can find some application at  www.windowsphone.com

Can i install a windows phone app in windows 7 pc?

How can i do that?

Comment: windows phone app in a windows7 pc? seriously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't install apps from the store to your computer, even if you have Windwos Phone SDK. You will need to use an actual phone.

BUT it is possible to load a windows phone 7 XAP file into the emulator without the solution or source files, (if a developer is sending it, apparently windows store precompile xaps files). In this case you will need WP SDK. Run the XapDeploy.exe application. It should be in:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Tools\XAP
>   Deployment

Select "Windows Phone Emulator" as the target and select what .xap application you would like to run.