# Windows Phone Emulator not able to sign in using email

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

i got problem with **Windows Phone Emulator**

i am not able to sign with email to download an app from marketplace

[image]

[image]

anybody have idea?

Answer (score 1):

The emulator is not a trusted platform for using the Microsoft Live ID. You will need to use an actual phone to set Microsoft account.

**see also**

[Cannot set Microsoft account in WP8 Emulator](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/dfd9ba6f-1d18-486e-aa53-7d0a65d44f12/cannot-set-microsoft-account-in-wp8-emulator?forum=wptools)

Comment: that means , i am not able to download an app from my emulator?

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21283868/windows-phone-app-in-windows-7-pc/21284675#21284675